# Server multiple tabs at the same time

Tags: php, apache, cakephp, ubuntu-10.04

Forgive me if this is a duplicate question, but I've spent the better part of an hour looking and couldn't find anything specific. Or I didn't know how to word the question.

Problem:

I administer a website which runs a PHP application using the CakePHP framework. We have an issue where if you want to open multiple tabs for the same domain, you have to wait for the 1st request's data to return before the other tab's data is returned.
 e.g. lets say I click a link which runs a heavy DB query and takes 5 seconds to return and render the page. But after clicking that link, I also click some other links for very light pages. These other tabs will not render until the first tab receives data back from the server.

I also know that the server side processing is done async. because even if I load 2 heavy tabs, as soon as the first returns the 2nd also returns and renders the page.

So... my question is, is this a code related issue or a config issue and how would I go about correcting this?

Stack:
Apache 2.2.14
PHP 5.3.2
CakePHP 2.4
Ubuntu 10.04

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

P.S. I know its possible because about a year or two ago, I managed to get this to work, but it messed something up with our sessions so I had to revert what I worked on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its actually a browser feature, though I can not find a good reference currently to it.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/H0AHdeAXSFo

is a topic but doesnt really show much. Is it possible to load the page and then load the results in though AJAX ? You do not then suffer from the same issues.

EDIT:

Answer above is wrong...
This is caused by session locking.

Example 4 on http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

```
<?php
// If we know we don't need to change anything in the
// session, we can just read and close rightaway to avoid
// locking the session file and blocking other pages
session_start([
    'cookie_lifetime' => 86400,
    'read_and_close'  => true,
]);
```

Comment: Yep, I could, but then we have over 2000 routes which would need to be modified amongst countless other actions. I did read that browsers limit it, but I'm sure I read 6 simultaneous requests.

I just want 2 or 3 to load at teh same time, or run 1 heavy one and keep working away in another tab.

Comment: Im not 100% sure that is the limit being hit, Thats the Max number of HTTP requests, This issue I could replicate with a single request to a page which just slept for 1 minute. Therefore well under the amount . I have starred this topic in case an answer to get around it. For referance I was using chrome when i seen this behaviour.

Comment: Just had an upvote on this. This answer is 100% wrong!!! This is caused by a session lock in PHP.

Comment: sorry only just saw that you'd replied to this message, could you elaborate please? How could I get this to work if at all possible? And lastly do you have any references to where you found this / where it could be fixed? thanks

Comment: Added something to the answer a few weeks back. Read and close and just close the session. Its there to make sure the session is clean and not being written to in multiple places